# Is it possible to use two context entities from two different database

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, edmx

Is it possible to use two context entities from two different database

Code connectiong to one entity:

```
 Using one FoodSupplyEntities
 using (var contextFood = new FoodSupplyEntities())
        {
        var _result = (from _FoodSupplyStatus in contextFood.FoodSupplyStatus
                      join _FoodQualityStatus in contextFood.FoodQualityStatus
```

But is it possible to join for example another table from a different entities from another server.?

Sample (Dont know but  it might gosomething like this.)

```
  using (var contextFood = new FoodSupplyEntities() and contextKitchenware = new KitchenwareEntities() )
        {
        var _result = (from _FoodSupplyStatus in contextFood.FoodSupplyStatus
                      join _KitchenwareSupplyStatus in contextKitchenware.KitchenwareSupplyStatus
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have 2 tables in 2 different databases:

1. User in Database1
2. Orders in Database2 where UserId of User table in database 1 is referring OrderedBy in Orders table.

I have Created 2 different context.
now i will create 2 queries for 2 different context and will make join on these queries on UserId and OrderedBy like:

```
List<OrderDetails> GetOrderDetails()
    {
        var users = this.TestDb1ModelUnit.GetRepository<User_Login>().GetAll();
        var orders = this.TestDb2ModelUnit.GetRepository<OrderDetail>().GetAll();

        var orderDetails = users.Join(orders,
            usr => usr.User_Id,
            ord => ord.OrderedBy,
            (usr, ord) => new { usr, ord }
            ).ToList(); 
    }
```